# Assembly Dependency Attribute

Tags: c#, xamarin, dependencies

I am studying Xamarin, and in one tutorial, I saw the code below:

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.IO;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(Notes.Droid.DadosEspecificos))]

namespace Notes.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "Notes", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }

    public class DadosEspecificos : IDadosEspecificos
    {
        public string CaminhoDB(string NomeDB)
        {
            return Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), NomeDB);
        }
    }
}
```

The project is a Cross-Platform Blank App (Xamarin.Forms Portable).

I would like to know what is the meaning of the line below:

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(Notes.Droid.DadosEspecificos))]

Why is it necessary ?

Thanks.

Comment: That is registering the `DadosEspecificos` class as an implementation of the `IDadosEspecificos` interface, which means that `DependencyService.Get< IDadosEspecificos >()` can be used in the shared code to create an instance of it. Review the following for details : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Forms allows developers to define behavior in platform-specific projects.dependency services finds the right platform implementation, allowing shared code to access the native functionality.

see here

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/

Comment: means if you want to access the GPS API in Android phone, you can access it through dependency service

Comment: that is a comment, now an answer.